# Should we cite the perspective (sect) that an answer comes from?

Tags: discussion, answers

Users will answer based on their particular sect & its relevant texts. Many readers will not know that a particular reference is common to one sect, but not another. Since we, rightfully, accept answers from all sects, shouldn't the reader be informed about the perspective of the answer (when relevant)?

Comment: Normally yes, but sometimes people dont rely on any sectarian interpretation of a text.

Comment: Not always one needs a particular interpretation, many a times most of philosophies do more or less agree with one interpretation. But sometimes when there exists a significant difference in the interpretations among various sects or philosophies, answerer should write "According to <xyz>, ........." in the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we want to handle discrepancies between belief systems on this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-do-we-want-to-handle-discrepancies-between-belief-systems-on-this-site)

Comment: This is about labeling the perspective of references (something factual that people new to Hinduism may not already know) not about handling discrepancies (disagreements within the community).