# 2021 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

Due to the short [election](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/election/1) cycle, the community hosted an abbreviated [question collection](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2124/2711), which I offered to help curate into a questionnaire.

Not every question was selected. All questions were positive scored, but there was a total of 16 suggestions — I tried to merge some related questions into a single entry, to try to maximize the number of questions picked, though.

As a candidate, your job is simple—post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes.Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

---

Candidate Answers:

- [user30612's answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2150/2711)
- [theLittleNaruto’s answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2151/20129)

---

> 1. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Hinduism Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?
> 2. Suppose that we are working on fabricating or refining a site policy and we have one meta discussion post for getting community consensus for making decision on that particular issue. If the community is somewhat evenly split over the issue, as a moderator, how do you solve such a controversial issue for which the community is divided over?
> 3. Despite [several clarifications](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21) by staff members, some users continue to believe this is a 'pro-Hindu site' as opposed to a 'site about Hinduism’, and want to censor views they don't agree with even when those views are backed with sources and citations. How do you plan to deal with users who use labels such as 'anti-scriptural', 'anti-Hindu', 'Marxist', 'Leftist', 'Asura', 'Abrahamic', etc. to target those that don't conform to their views?
> 4. What is your take on answers that provide quotes from modern experts which are clearly against scriptures?
> 5. How would you handle arguments (be them comments or conversations in chat) because of different beliefs among the users, or that are just non-constructive in nature? (irrespective of flagged or not flagged)
> 6. How would you handle a question/answer which is on-topic but vaguely presented and hurting the sentiments of (a) some users and (b) many users?
> 7. How do you deal with the users who strategically try to *mislead* the site with their answers by pushing pressure points with their biases?
> 8. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 9. How would you handle flags on old positively-scored answers lacking valid sources?
> 10. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 11. Even if the moderators’ main focus is to handle flags, do you plan to be active in chat and on Meta?

Comment: So, wannabe mods back to school :p only difference is that the question paper is already leaked.

Comment: Btw user CR241 wants to withdraw his nomination. Here you can see his comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38156/original-version-of-raghupati-raghav-raja-ram-bhajan/38163?noredirect=1#comment139409_38163 @Archit

Answer (score 5):

## TheLittleNaruto

> 1. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Hinduism Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

- Biggest problem is many users still don't know how to use their privileges properly. We can work on educating them about their privileges.

> 2. Suppose that we are working on fabricating or refining a site policy and we have one meta discussion post for getting community consensus for making decision on that particular issue. If the community is somewhat evenly split over the issue, as a moderator, how do you solve such a controversial issue for which the community is divided over?

- For the site the community is the most valuable. Just like the sun cannot be separated from its heat and light, so also the site and community are the same entity. If the site is divided equally it means a view has not been arrived at yet not action can be taken yet. Being an objective moderator, taking sides would be uncalled for. Yet if requested by the community I will discuss the issue with the moderation team and hope to arrive at a reasonable conclusion to appropriately lead the site.

> 3. Despite several clarifications by staff members, some users continue to believe this is a 'pro-Hindu site' as opposed to a 'site about Hinduism’, and want to censor views they don't agree with even when those views are backed with sources and citations. How do you plan to deal with users who use labels such as 'anti-scriptural', 'anti-Hindu', 'Marxist', 'Leftist', 'Asura', 'Abrahamic', etc. to target those that don't conform to their views?

- I do not wish to pick sides by saying I don’t support such comments specifically or do support such comments specifically. Being a moderator I will deal with all comments brought to my notice objectively. Without going into the specific nature of the terms mentioned in the question, I will talk for all comments generally. As I state below too, everyone is free to express their views in a constructive manner without hurting anyone’s sentiments. Any user aggrieved by any comments (be them of any nature) which are in *contravention of the code of conduct or rude and abusive*can flag them in the appropriate criteria and shall be dealt with it in the usual manner depending on the severity of the issue - deletion, and a repeated rude and abusive offender shall find a place in the penalty box.

> 4. What is your take on answers that provide quotes from modern experts which are clearly against scriptures?

- When I’m in the shoes of a moderator, I’m not expected to involve my personal beliefs about such topics. I will do my duty is to implement the majority’s view of the community that has been established after rigorous discussion on meta. As my personal beliefs won’t deride necessary moderator action, I don’t think it is important to express them as such and create a divide between the community at such a crucial time for the site.

> 5. How would you handle arguments (be them comments or conversations in chat) because of different beliefs among the users, or that are just non-constructive in nature? (irrespective of flagged or not flagged)

- Everyone is entitled to their views. Arguments are not going to stop and it is very difficult to choose sides. It is not correct for a moderator to interfere in every non-flagged conversation. It is also not possible for moderators to read each and every non-flagged content. Comments in the nature of Non-constructive extended discussions shall be simply moved to chat. If they’re flagged as rude or abusive they shall be dealt with appropriately by deleting them.

> 6. How would you handle a question/answer which is on-topic but vaguely presented and hurting the sentiments of (a) some users and (b) many users?

- As I state below and have stated above, any post hurting sentiments may be flagged using the appropriate flag. As for posts hurting sentiments which are on topic there is a [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/need-to-take-down-abysmal-posts-from-the-main-site?r=SearchResults) roughly discussing a similar issue. Whatever be the majority view of the community will be my duty to implement.

> 7. How do you deal with the users who strategically try to mislead the site with their answers by pushing pressure points with their biases?

- I’d request privileged users to flag such misleading posts and they shall be dealt with in accordance with well established site policies - citation banners, requesting user to be within the boundary demarcated by policies, deleting misleading posts, and on repeated disobedience the user visits the penalty box - these are among the options depending upon the severity of the issue.

> 8. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

- Having valuable answers or not is not a criterion to be biased against certain users’ who have behaviour in gross contravention of the code of conduct. Having an argument in the and expressing ones views does not cause for any authoritative action against any user. Yes if users are having an extended discussion (whether argument or not) in the comments section, the comments shall be moved to chat. If any particular user’s behaviour, irrespective of his valuable questions and answers, is against the code of conduct or well established site rules and policies framed from time to time on meta, then the user maybe informed about the fact of his overstepping the limits (also by other users). If he yet continues then depending on the severity of the case, the necessary authoritative action shall be taken such as deleting hurtful comments,  penalty box in case of extreme misbehaviour.

> 9. How would you handle flags on old positively-scored answers lacking valid sources?

- Our site is one which has a wonderful and unique feature of citing valid sources for answers, rendering very high quality authentic content as a consequence. This is a well established policy. If an answer does not cite valid sources, then it is not entirely in accordance with the established policy on meta. Our cite has this unique feature too where a banner is placed atop an answer flagged as such. Hence such a banner will be placed and the answer will be given an opportunity for improvement. If there is no improvement whatsoever, then any further action as per decided policy will be taken, on being flagged by users and discussion with other mods if required.

> 10. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

- Everyone has a different viewpoint for committing certain actions and the mod who performed any of the above mentioned acts, would have had a valid reason too. In case of conflict of opinion as a team of mods eagerly leading the site, I wold discuss the reasons with them to arrive at a conclusion. Mostly I’m sure we would be able to arrive at which is the correct course of action. If however the issue remains un-resolvable then I would request the mod team to raise a question on meta and let our fellow community members provide their valuable inputs.

> 11. Even if the moderators’ main focus is to handle flags, do you plan to be active in chat and on Meta?

- Yes! Guess that has become my habit. :P

Comment: Can you elaborate more on number one? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### user30612

Yes. Hinduism is a culture developed in India and region around. But it got the status of a religion when the invading rulers did not find any single name for the religious pratice by the people in this region.

The Hinduism is known for the polytheism worldwide because it allowed freedom to follow/worship any Big-Demigod as "ishta-devta". Unlike other religions which got their names as per the respective messengers/promoters, the Hinduism got its name for its cultural practices. All other religions suggested their name in their scriptures. But we never find the word "Hindu" or "Hinduism" in any of the scriptures of Hinduism. However we find three type of God realisation/following methodologies as "Bhakti", "Yog" and "Brahman-Jnan" in their respective God realisation, by all the Indian Vedic Scripture.

> 1. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Hinduism Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

Answer #1: Hinduism at Stackexchange has no challenges from outside. Yes but sometimes we can observe a trade-off between independent and imposed discussions. This can be solved naturally due to the independent nature of the Internet and its community with time.

> 2. Suppose that we are working on fabricating or refining a site policy and we have one meta discussion post for getting community consensus for making decision on that particular issue. If the community is somewhat evenly split over the issue, as a moderator, how do you solve such a controversial issue for which the community is divided over?
> 3. Despite several clarifications by staff members, some users continue to believe this is a 'pro-Hindu site' as opposed to a 'site about Hinduism’, and want to censor views they don't agree with even when those views are backed with sources and citations. How do you plan to deal with users who use labels such as 'anti-scriptural', 'anti-Hindu', 'Marxist', 'Leftist', 'Asura', 'Abrahamic', etc. to target those that don't conform to their views?

Answer #2 & 3:  "munde munde matir bhinna, tunde tunde sarsvati". The vedic mantra suggests the beauty of diversity of thoughts. The Scripture says, " every scripture is given by the inspiration of God". Yes, but the misinterpretations can be avoided/ignored by giving citations from authentic sources. The Stackexchange is the independent discussion and knowledge sharing platform for the entire internet global community.

> 4. What is your take on answers that provide quotes from modern experts which are clearly against scriptures?

Answer #4 "Don't say yes when you want to say (k)no(w)". The modern views on scripture if are like old methods of blasphemy, then shouldn't be allowed. Yes. if the views are not hurting the sentiments of anyone could be welcomed.

> 5. How would you handle arguments (be them comments or conversations in chat) because of different beliefs among the users, or that are just non-constructive in nature? (irrespective of flagged or not flagged)

Answer #5: If don't have time, taking their leave (leaving the room) would be the best resolution. Otherwise, it doesn't matter to carry on any interesting discussion.

> 6. How would you handle a question/answer which is on-topic but vaguely presented and hurting the sentiments of (a) some users and (b) many users?

Answer #6: "Keep it! we don't want it right now".

> 7. How do you deal with the users who strategically try to mislead the site with their answers by pushing pressure points with their biases?

Answer #7: Is it really possible to mislead a website. Strange !! but we think the security experts are there to handle that hacker.

> 8. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Answer #8: No comments on that, at this point in time.

> 9. How would you handle flags on old positively-scored answers lacking valid sources?

Answer #9: We need to ask the permission to help him/her edit the original post with some authentic unbiased sources.

> 10. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Answer #10: The moderators need to have a chatroom to discuss on that kind of issues. If we don't take care of our genuine users/visitors, other websites do take care of those disgruntled.

> 11. Even if the moderators’ main focus is to handle flags, do you plan to be active in chat and on Meta?

Answer #11 Yes! Sure!!