# The "Best" and the most "Underrated" QnAs ever, according to you?

Tags: discussion, community

I'm thinking if everyone would be interested in giving a short list of Questions and Answers which in their "humble" opinion are the Best and/or the most Underrated on the MAINS?

Something in the Following format:

Best Questions:

1. Cyz
2. Pqr
3. Rst etc.

Best Answers:

1. Pqr
2. Otr
3. Fgt etc.

Most Underrated Questions:

1. Xyz
2. Rty
3. Ytr etc.

Most Underrated Answers:

1. Ftp
2. Kpy
3. Svd etc.

(*Depending on one's choice, one may add as many items (Questions or Answers) in a particular sub-list, while choosing or omitting to answer whichever "Main Heading" they want*. This list, of course can be regularly updated by the OPs)

This way, we might be able to see more content without much effort to scroll through the site (this is for "lazy-hands :D) and also have a good repository of individual-opinion based community voted QnAs too.

**An example of an "Underrated Answer" can be found in this Question:**
[How many wives did Lord Shiva have?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/how-many-wives-did-lord-shiva-have)

From the sheer difference between the Votes given to an "unreputed-source" answer and the "Properly-sourced" Answer - Gives a reflection of the kind of "aceeptable & Higly-voted" poor-content the initial days of site endured with.

---

<sup>I have deliberately ommited the Main heading corresponding to "Most Overrated QnAs" because that per say, might be "controversial* and non-conducive to CoC.</sup>

Comment: For the underrated answers section I was also thinking to post a meta question similar to this! There are plenty of scripture based answers which are underrated which can be liberated using upvotes and bounties! Specially users in the beginning days of this site have accepted pretty much bogus answers (not based on scriptures) and they are ruining the image of our site by accepting such answers. Some of them are even no more active. If we get underrated answers we can atleast bring them to little bit top (if they deserve). We may also announce bounties to underrated answers if needed...

Comment: *"There are plenty of scripture based answers which are underrated which can be liberated using upvotes and bounties"* - Yes. @Tezz Actually, going through most answers from the past, one finds that almost all answers are cited with only "Wikipedia" as a source. And then random blogs, or dead sites, etc. Sometimes, even opinions as answers have been accepted by the OPs. Very unfortunate situation flr QnAs in the beginning days.

Comment: @Vivikta I had already answered a Meta regarding this [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/742/lets-delete-all-old-answers-from-early-days-of-the-site-that-lack-any-reference/751#751) There most have agreed with that answer. So if a question has even a single scripture based answer all other bogus answers can be deleted. But moderators aren't enforcing that. Seems that we should enforce moderators to do that or raise another seperate meta for deletion.

Comment: Maybe first there needs to be a proper META on the procedure of how that might be implemented. For ex: What timeline we're taking as the deadline for QnAs to be designated the "Old-enough to be deleted for lack of citations". Then, yes, surely we'll have to proceed and the active users along with the "active" Moderators will have to work hard to get the mammoth task done or even Started at all. @Tezz

Comment: @Vivikta yes we basically need a system like: 'If an answer has **citation banner** and it is more than **this days old**, automatically **delete** that answer.' So, that it becomes easy for moderators also.

Comment: What's the definition of underrated (like less than x votes) and can one add their own posts  in underrated and/or best list?

Comment: Well @YDS , I think it's a personal choice to "Self-Nominate" oneself: However, IMHO, I think it's better if the recommendation comes from a third-person rather than the OPs of the QnAs themselves. It's like, - *"It's not forbidden, however, not to be encouraged or applauded too"*

Comment: Underrated is subjective - will always depend upon the observer. Tips can be - If the other answers in the thread with "lesser quality", ATY, are more voted than the deserving ones,  or something on that line perhaps.