# Posts that offend but have scriptural sanction seem to be allowed. But how about offensive AND unsupported material?

Tags: discussion

For example

[Apart from the Padma Purana, does any other Purana say that Adi Shankaracharya will teach mayavadi philosophy?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20228/apart-from-the-padma-purana-does-any-other-purana-say-that-adi-shankaracharya-w)

This post just slings mud on a revered teacher and on a revered deity.

The authority?

It is in "scripture".

The other perennial of hate - "Tamasic Purana" is back again recently.

But this post

[How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/259#259)

Has this offensive material - but it doesn't seem to have scriptural sanction.  How can the poster of this material be asked to either support it or remove it?

> it should be noted that even though Shiva is the son of Brahma and Brahma is the son of Vishnu, Shiva is still in some sense also a direct creation of Vishnu. As Krishna says in the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata, "The ancestors of civilization, and entities such as Shiva, were created by Me. They do not know of this because they are illusioned by My cosmic material energies."

Comment: This is insane! I have never meant to sling mud on Adi Shankara. When I posted that question, I myself was an Advaitin. You can't just accuse me of insulting Adi Shankara. If I have disrespected Adi Shankara genuinely, may Vishnu curse me to a painful death.

Comment: Why do you always feel everybody has a motive for posting any question? You can't make such claims without knowing me. You even go to extent to say that I'm a 40 year old in a disguise of a 16 year old.

Comment: "The other perennial of hate - "Tamasic Purana" is back again recently." - Why do you think everything is motivated by hate?

Comment: a dear relative who is no more read the Siva Purana for decades every day.  If people cite 'scripture" to say it is Tamasic and would lead to hell - it walks like hate,  swims like hate and quacks like hate - it IS hate.  The American constitution said blacks are 3/5 of a person - but now it is unacceptable.  There is material in what we call scripture that is no longer acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. We allow all scriptures and [words of Acharyas](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500) of all philosophies and sects. Some Acharyas have criticized other philosophies or Acharyas strongly and followers of other philosophers might be offended. But since we allow all Scriptures and words of Swamis and Acharyas, **don't flag such content**. We also suggest avoiding posts that target [others beliefs](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1122/3500).

[Personal experience](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/811/3500) is never recommended as source. If you find some answer (or even some portion of it) which has no *valid source*, flag for Moderation attention. Mods will notify users and that content may be removed if concerned user fails to provide proper source . If you even find any content that is offensive for you and  has no *valid source*, flag that content for moderator attention. Mods will check the content and take necessary action.

Comment: Thanks @The Destroyer  Please consider my post above as notification that the post  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-were-the-trimurthi-born/259#259 has unsourced material.

Comment: @SK Ok. You can directly flag using "in need of moderator attention".

Comment: @SK Just checked.  Link he provided has that quote.

Comment: "Link he provided has that quote". – @The Destroyer - not true some unfounded website may have it - but it doesn't seem to be in the Mahabharta Moksha Dharma Parva.  Do you honestly think Vyasa would write something like this? please see  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32204/does-moksha-dharma-parva-contain-this-alleged-quotation-from-it

Comment: @SK The link doesn't explicitly say where it can be found in MhB. But link is valid only which is site of Gaudiya Vaishnavas. Even if it is found in Mahabharata , Sanskrit word could be Rudra, which generally means  Layakaraka alone,  not Supreme Shiva in Puranas and Ithihasas parlance.  But wrong or right doesn't come under purview of moderation.

Comment: A Website is not a source.  As long as this post stands without corroboration from scripture - this site will be a joke @The Destroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer The Shanti Parva verse is indeed missing in the Mahabharata but one can't go on to say it was never present in the Mahabharata because it's quite possible such verses existed before since Baladeva Vidyabhusana quoted it.

Comment: @SK It comes from Baladeva Vidyabhusana's Vishnu Sahasranamam commentary.

Comment: @SK Yes, maybe. Or even it might be in  a different recension of Mahabharata. All scriptures have multiple versions/recensions. As long as it is quoted by an Acharya, it should be allowed. You should only flag if the verse was never quoted by an Acharya or any scripture.

Comment: Can you find it here? http://www.vrindavana.net/academy/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/visnu-sahasra-nama-baladeva-I.pdf

Comment: @SK Check here (Prologue, Text 7) : http://ebooks.iskcondesiretree.com/pdf/Gaudiya_Books%20/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Vishnu_Sahasra_Nama.pdf

Comment: It is NOT in the source I linked to - which actually has facsimile images of the printed book. It says "VSN with the commentary of Srila Baladeva Vidyabhusana".  I am not convinced that Vidyabhusana actually wrote the extra verses in the source you linked to.  At any rate no known edition of Mahabharata has the verse.

Comment: @SK Can't say, I can't read Sanskrit

Comment: @SK It is also present in the link you have provided. Check page 5 of 80 in PDF. Right page. Just under Esha me sarvadharmanaam..  Another statement is in page 49 of 80 in PDF in penultimate paragraph of left page.

Comment: @SK I guess that solves it. Sarvabhouma has identified the pages. You should apologise to Keshav now.

Comment: "You should apologise to Keshav now. " - yeah, right.