# What is clear difference between "Plagiarism " And "Opinion based answer"

Tags: support

Pls. Refer  [Why eating rice is prohibited on Ekadashi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13854/why-eating-rice-is-prohibited-on-ekadashi)  for my comment on "Plagiarism. I want to know  the difference between Plagiarism and opinion based answer?.

Is it against the rules that  for  a novice person who have just started to learn to give answers and is still learning the basics in background , to take some initial information \text from some other sources like other websites for some time at least ?

secondly for the same if novice provides  his own answer for the same with his own belief /nohow can it be termed as opinion based answer and requires proof. And shall be liable to be  flagged so.

Comment: It is absolutely fine to quote sources like scriptures, books, or websites.  But you should put the text you're copying and pasting within blockquotes, and you should mention the source of the text you're copying and pasting.  It's only if you copy and paste text from a website without crediting the source that it becomes plagiarism.

Comment: @ Keshav Shrinivasan , very thanks for your answer. Will keep that in mind .

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, I suggest you take a look at my answers: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan?tab=answers Almost all of them contain quotes from sources.

Comment: ok I will surely check them all . :)

Comment: Related post [The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Plagiarism

Plagiarism already been discussed in meta before:

[The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version)

To understand it more clearly Stack exchange main meta also have similar post

[What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)

I am writing it word to word here for clearing it:

> > Important: **Don't be a lynch mob, even if you're (understandably) angry.** Do not pile  downvotes on recently uncovered plagiators'
> >     answers. Let the moderators handle it - they will destroy any
> >     occurrences of egregious plagiarism, and may suspend the user for a
> >     while.
>
> ## 1. Double-check
>
> Check again whether the OP didn't add a source somewhere after all.
>   Sometimes it is at the end of the copied text, or hidden behind a
>   single-word link. Check out all the links in the answer. Sometimes
>   they get hidden by bad formatting - it's worth clicking 'edit' just
>   for one final check to make sure.
>
> Make sure that the original source you found really is a legit
>   source, and not one of the [ripoff sites copying Stack Overflow
>   content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) (efreedom.us, etc.) or some other content aggregator.
>
> ## 2. Edit or flag  If it looks like a **minor, single incident**, editing the attribution in is the way to go. You can do that yourself,
>
> either directly or through a suggested edit. Put the attribution in
>   front of the copied material, and  put everything into blockquotes
>   that isn't the OP's original speech. Use nice wording, like `From the
>   Wikipedia Article on xyz:` After that, proceed to step 3.
>
> If it looks like there is an **egregious pattern of plagiarism,**
>   and deletions seem necessary, flag for moderator attention.  Explain 
>   that you believe the answer has been plagiarized, and paste the source
>   URL into a comment underneath, say `Plagiarism: copied without
>   attribution from ....`
>
> If your flag gets declined, flag again and/or raise the issue on Meta.
>   [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156080/moderator-declined-a-plagiarism-flag) is previous discussion.
>
> ## 3. Educate the OP The OP may be innocent(-ish) simply because they're ignorant of how gravely wrong  plagiarism is - this is the
>
> case more often than one would believe. If there is no indication the
>   community has had a conversation with them about the issue, consider
>   leaving a polite comment along the lines of
>
> > Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from (insert URL here). You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit.
> >     This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on Stack Overflow.
> >     Remember to **always** add prominent attribution when using other
> >     sources. Thanks!
>
> or a more nicely worded suggestion from [JMort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156086/138112):
>
> > Hi User, it looks like you just copied most of this content from this blog . Can you edit your post and give attribution to the author?
> >     Plagiarism isn't really welcomed on Stack Overflow, and it's always
> >     nice to give credit where credit is due. Good luck!
>
> ## 4. Go hunt for more
>
> Moderators have enough to do already - they won't be able to check out
>   a user's entire profile for further instances of plagiarism. If you
>   feel like it, take that task upon yourself, and flag each occurrence
>   as described above.

## For "Opinion based answer”

We can refer [Shog9's words](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/191/76) as official statement to our [different meta question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/let-us-stop-asking-for-sources-every-time) :

> We definitely don't want folks [composing their answers entirely of
>   someone else's work](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version), but [backing up their assertions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-we-enforce-quotations-of-scripture-references/2#2) should
>   be considered *normal*.
>
> These two ideals don't really conflict with each other either. You
>   should be able to *summarize* a scripture and *relate it to the
>   asker's question* in your own words, while still tying it back to a
>   more canonical source.
>
> In other words, answerers should strive to *share their own
>   interpretations* but back them up by references to verifiable sources.